# PDF accessibility scanner CLI

Tags: pdf, accessibility

I have a bunch of PDFs on our website.

We are required to section 508 scan these documents. We use Adobe to check this thus far.

But we need to set up an automated job that checks these PDFs for compliance on a schedule.

Is there a CLI option to scan PDF files for compliance? I would like to set up an automated job to check these.

Or can Adobe be used to accessibility scan via the command line/CLI?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some resources that might help:

- Create a [Batch Sequence](https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/library/batch/index.html#creating-and-running-a-batch-sequence)
  , still needs to be triggered manually
- Maybe pair a Batch Sequence with this [add-on](https://evermap.com/autobatch.asp); but that may not be a ["valid use of Acrobat"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42958666/246801)

Have you looked at the Action Wizard?

Comment: i would need CLI examples, like batch scripts i can run, etc.